# How to test an Angular directive was applied on the element

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

In my app I have a button with a simple click event and a stopPropagation directive applied on it.

Here is the component template:

```
<button (click)="closeElement()" [stopPropagation]>
    Close
</button>
```

The directive simply catch any event on the element and triggers an `$event.stopPropagation()` on any event.

The directive is tested by itself with its own tests. But how, in the component, to test the directive is actually applied?

Comment: Well create a tag with a click action, and see if your directive prevents it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a spy like explained in https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html. By spying on the function of your directive you can verify that it is called when the button is clicked using 'toHaveBeenCalled'.

```
it("tracks that the spy was called", function() {

let spy= spyOn(<yourDirective>, 'stopPropagation');

..trigger click event...
expect(stopPropagation).toHaveBeenCalled();});
```

With more code i could probably give a more elaborate coding example but this should lead you on the right track.

Comment: Do you think I should test if the HTML attribute is present on the element?

Comment: You could do that to double check whether not only your directive was called but also if it took effect on you element by using the TestBed of Angular and check on the nativeElement of your fixture and use a querySelector to target your specific HTML element see [Angular Testing](https://angular.io/guide/testing#final-setup-and-tests) . 

If you want to do that depends a bit on your projects testing policy. I'd say do it once as a proof, but don't test every element the directive is used on. Let me know if I can help you further.

Comment: Thanks for advices :)